# How @ values are looked up from XML files in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In Android studio, if I write:

```
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
```

The value `dark_grey` is looked up in `res/values/colors.xml`.

If I have:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_reminders" />
```

The value is looked up as `res/layout/content_reminders.xml`.

Questions:

- How does the lookup happen *exactly*?
- How can you set *more* lookup directories? For example what if I wanted to have `@layout2/something_else` there? Or is it not allowed? And in either case, where is `@layout` looked up from? Is it in the project's config?

**[ADDED QUESTION]**

- How does Gradle deal with the ambiguity?

The format of the two is very different: one is `@color/dark_grey` and one is `@layout/content_reminders`.  Even accepting that the folders `res/layout` and `res/values` are special and treated it in a special way, how does Gradle know that when I type `@layout/content_reminder`, I am not talking about the value `content_reminder` in the file `res/values/layout.xml` (as opposed to the file `layout.xml` under `res/layout`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio indexes your `resources`. Whatever you put in `res/values/xxxxx.xml` is indexed with the tag used like `<color>` or `<string>`, along with the line number in the xml file.

The indexing happens because it's more effective and you need to show all options during autoComplete. So why you click on `@color/dark_grey`, it searches the index and goes the line number in the file where `drak_grey` is defined. This is how `lookup` work in Studio.

You can't have something as `@layout2` in `<include>` tag, because there is no provision for you to add it. However you can add your own attributes for your custom View or ViewGroup. Even in that case, Android Studio does the lookup for you, and you need not do any additional stuff.

As for the scope, it happens in the `Project` scope. All `resources` in your dependencies (modules) will be lookedup. If you have a module, but you haven't added it as a dependency, then the module won't be used for lookup. I think the the indexing and lookup happens not on the original source files, but rather on the files generated in the gradle build.

`layout`,`color`, `string` and other tags are special. When you type `@layout/` the auto complete will show all the layout files. This thing is done in the Android Studio. These tags are understood by the IDE. So you can't introduce new tags.

How Gradle identifies this? Well, I am not sure if Gradle is the one behind it. The `Build Tools` that comes with your SDK might be responsible.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I am confused as the format of the two is very different: one is `@color/dark_grey` and one is `@layout/content_reminders`. They are so different... how does it know, for the first one, to look into color.xml (and where)? I would understand if they were `@layout/content_reminders` and `@values/color:dark_grey` (or something like that) so that there was some kind of consistency (`@path:[value]`). But like this... what is the actual format...?

Comment: Also if _everything_ in the `res` folder is indexed, what stops me from adding a `layout2` folder there and reference it? (I mean, it DOESN'T work, but why...? Are the `layout` and the `values` folders special..?)

Comment: And even accepting that the folders `res/layout` and `res/values` are special and treated it in a special way, how does it know that when I type `@layout/content_reminder`, I am not talking about the value `content_reminder` in the file `res/values/layout.xml` (as opposed to the file `layout.xml` under `res/layout` ...

Comment: I added a question... if you feel like it, please update the answer so that everything is in one spot!

Comment: yes, `layout`,'color`, 'string' and other tags are special. When you type `@layout/` the auto complete will show all the `layout` files. This thing is done in the Android Studio. These tags are understood by the IDE. So you can't introduce new tags.

Comment: Is there a list of _all_ of the "special" tags available?

Answer (score -1):

**The android SDK generates a unique Integer value to each of the file under res/values folder** this value is used at run time to look up for that particular resource.**This file is can be seen by opening your generated file R.java under generated folder of your app**.

Answer (score -1):

no no no, You can not use the @layout2/something_else.
compiler just looked up to @layout.

Answer (score -2):

```
<include layout="@layout/a" />
```

try press Alt+Insert when mouse on `@layout/a`;

Comment: Understand the question properly.